# Could not resolve dependencies for project spmf ca.pfv pom.xml

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml, spmd, mvn-repo

I am working on open source maven project that use several mining dependencies.
after write this command into component `mvn clean install` I got ERROR in pom.xml file,enter code here that version of spmf is wrong.

```
<groupId>ca.pfv</groupId>
<artifactId>spmf</artifactId>
<version>2.33</version> // !!!
```

full error:

> omponents-spmanalysis: Could not resolve dependencies for project
>   info.collide:components-spmanalysis:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to
>   find ca.pfv:spmf:jar:2.33

I tried to use different versions but same error at maven install.

Comment: Where should this dependency exist? In Central it does not exist...so I assume you should have in your own local repository...

Comment: I am the founder of SPMF and it has not been added to Maven by me. So I don't know who manage that thing in Maven. ;-)